# Django FieldError: Unknown fields specified

Tags: python, django, forms

I am getting this error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (first_name, username, last_name) specified for SystemUser
```

Here is my model. I extended the User model since I want to add additional fields to it.

```
class SystemUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    POSITION_CHOICES = (
        ('ADMIN', 'Admin'),
        ('SALES EMPLOYEE', 'Sales Employee'),
        ('INVENTORY MANAGER', 'Inventory Manager'),
        ('FINANCIAL OFFICER', 'Financial Officer'),
        ('PROJECT HEAD', 'Project Head'),
        ('SHIPPER', 'Shipper'),
        ('SUPPLIER', 'Supplier')
    )
    position = models.CharField(choices=POSITION_CHOICES, max_length=1)
```

Here is my forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = SystemUser
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'position']
```

Comment: try by using AbstractUser on class instead of models.Model or add on_delete & related_name on user field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre `SystemUser` is not extending the django `AbstractUser` model, therefore the fields does not exist:

replace

```
class SystemUser(models.Model)
```

with

```
from django.models import AbstractUser
class SystemUser(AbstractUser)
```

Edit:
Use [`AbstractUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) as base class for your new user model as Pije76 suggests in his comment .

Comment: What is the difference between User and AbstractUser?